# How can I add a new key with a value to an object in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I have a function whose task is to count the price of a product after a discount. However as a result I get objects without this value (totalPrice). Where am I making mistake?

```
const arrayObj = [
    {
        basePrice: 12,
        discount: 3,
    },
    {
        basePrice: 12,
        discount: 2,
    },
    {
        basePrice: 8,
        discount: 2,
    },
];

interface Product {
    basePrice: number;
    discount: number;
    totalPrice?: number;
}
const countTotalPrice = (products: Product[]): Product[] => {
    const calculateTotalPrice = (
        basePrice: number,
        discount: number,
        totalPrice?: number
    ): void => {
    
        totalPrice = basePrice - discount;
    };

    products.forEach((product) =>
        calculateTotalPrice(
            product.basePrice,
            product.discount,
            product.totalPrice
        )
    );
    return products;
};
console.log(countTotalPrice(arrayObj));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not modifying products in your array.
You have two options:

- use `products.forEach` and pass in a function that modifies a product. Return modified products.
- use `products.map` and pass in a function that takes a product and creates new object with additional property, return the result of mapping.

I would argue that 2nd approach is more idiomatic in JS/TS.

```ts
const countTotalPrice = (products: Product[]): Product[] => {
  return products.map((product) => 
    ({    // the parentheses are necessary in this position
          // we want object literal, not code block
          ...product,
          totalPrice: product.basePrice - product.discount
    })
  );
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwXAngeQEYCsYF4YDaAUDKTAN4lnUZwQCmACggJbD0BcMAjAEwA0VaqQAmLCKACuYKFwDMg6gF9FZSsLK0GzNpx4ChwsRJDTZMA8tWl1GmFqat2XABzWj4qTK6WyKogC6ANxERCwy9AgAZnDsMMwgIpLAsLakDjrOMGCSALYYkSHUxl7mOfmFhlAgUHAANpn0APxc5QUIIUqhoJCwpQAqNfWNeDAAFAAOCInJUBBcCUkpBAEAlAvTS1AreAB8FFQI9FCSCGAwUzMpEAB0uXATY5Obs6t7MIZjaXY3v5db7g01VqDScen%20sxuGTBMAAtBcXikbiVTDJDEpVlRVp1DEQehAQHV6Dc6iAAOZjAZDUG6MaIZDobCrbFAA)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
const countTotalPrice = (products: Product[]): Product[] => {
const calculateTotalPrice = (
 p:Product 
): void => {
    

    p.totalPrice = p.basePrice -p. discount;
};

products.forEach((product) =>
    calculateTotalPrice(
        product
    )
);
return products;
};
```

Comment: Rather than just posting a new code-snippet, you should explain what is wrong in OP's code and how your code fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) combined with [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
interface Product {
  basePrice: number;
  discount: number;
  totalPrice?: number;
}

const arrayObj: Product[] = [{ basePrice: 12, discount: 3 },{ basePrice: 12, discount: 2 },{ basePrice: 8, discount: 2 },];

const countTotalPrice = (products: Product[]): Product[] =>
  products.map((p) => ({
    ...p,
    totalPrice: p.basePrice - p.discount,
  }));
```

Code example without TypeScript:

```js
const arrayObj = [{basePrice: 12,discount: 3,},{basePrice: 12,discount: 2,},{basePrice: 8,discount: 2,},]

const countTotalPrice = (products) =>
  products.map((p) => ({
    ...p,
    totalPrice: p.basePrice - p.discount,
  }))

console.log(countTotalPrice(arrayObj))
```